# Specify multiple columns with nth-child()

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm using nth-child in my jquery selector to identify columns to modify. I have 5 columns (1-5) and I want to modify only 2,3, and 4. Is there a way to do this with nth-child? Something like:

```
$('#example tbody tr td:nth-child(2||3||4)')
```

I have tried several combinations but nothing seems to work. Im pretty new to jQuery selectors any help you could throw at me would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, 
Joe Chin

Comment: Can you not add any ids/classes to the columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#example tbody tr td:not(:last-child, :first-child)')
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `.nextUntil()` like this:

```
$('#example tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').nextUntil(':nth-child(5)');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Thanks, this also does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use slice, it is more dynamic.

```
$('#example tbody tr td').slice(1,4)
```

Heres the [API](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) for the slice method.

Comment: This wouldn't work on a per-row basis. It would be a slice of all the `<td>` elements found.

Comment: Thanks, this I've never seen this method before but its going to be pretty handy I'm sure.

Comment: That's not correct. The other two answers do work on a per-row basis because the `td` selectors used are some variation of `nth-child`. They both will select the 2nd through 4th columns of every row. Yours doesn't do that because it only grabs a small slice of the entire set. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/m9JH7/